# How to create a callback in laravel validation when it failed-validated and passed-validated?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-validation

I have here a validation in my custom request file.

```
class AuthRequest extends FormRequest
{
    public function store()
    {
        return $this->validate([
            'first_name' => ['required','min:2','max:30',new PersonNameRule],
            'last_name' => ['required','min:2','max:30',new PersonNameRule],
            'username' => ['required','confirmed',new UsernameRule]
        ]);
    }

    public function rules(){ return []; }
}
```

In my controller, this is how use it.

```
public function store(AuthRequest $request)
{
    $data = $request->store();

    return request()->all();
}
```

My question is how can I do these things below:

- **when validation failed** - create a session / `session(['attempt' => session('attempt')+1 ?? 1]);`
- **when validation passed** - destroy the session / `session()->forget('attempt')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[@mrhn](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2760986/mrhn) is right you did not fill the rules inside the function, so the `FormRequest` will always return false. What you did instead, you prefer to create your own method(s) and by using the `$this->validate()`.

Now here's how to achieve your problem, in file **..\Illuminate\Validation\Validator.php** find the `validate()` function, and put those session you desired to perform, like these below.

```
public function validate()
{
    if ($this->fails()) {
        session(['attempt' => session('attempt')+1 ?? 1]);
        throw new ValidationException($this);
    }else{
        session()->forget('attempt');
    }

    return $this->validated();
}
```

> The solution above is global which means it will perform everytime you use `$this->validate()`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Validator` instance instead of calling `validate()`

```
    $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
         'first_name' => ['required','min:2','max:30',new PersonNameRule],
         'last_name' => ['required','min:2','max:30',new PersonNameRule],
         'username' => ['required','confirmed',new UsernameRule]
    ]);

    if ($validator->fails()) {
        // create a session
    } else {
        // destroy the session
    }
```

You can see more in the doc here: https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/validation#manually-creating-validators

Comment: I use custom request Sir, I want to keep the `validate()`, I no want to import another validator inside the custom request that extends FormRequest.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly i will convert your validation to a form request, this will automatically resolve when injected into a controller.

```
UserCreateRequest extends FormRequest {
    public function rules() {
        'first_name' => ['required','min:2','max:30',new PersonNameRule],
        'last_name' => ['required','min:2','max:30',new PersonNameRule],
        'username' => ['required','confirmed',new UsernameRule]
    }
}
```

To use it inject it like so.

```
public create(UserCreateRequest $request) {
    ...
}
```

Here you can utilize two callback methods `passedValidation()` and `failedValidation()`, in your form request.

```
protected function failedValidation(Validator $validator) {
    session(['attempt' => session('attempt')+1 ?? 1]);

    return parent::failedValidation($validator);
}

protected function passedValidation() {
    session()->forget('attempt')

    return parent::passedValidation();
}
```

Comment: sir it returns **Class App\Http\Requests\AuthRequest does not exist** and by the way I created a custom method instead of rules method. See my updated full code

Comment: Then something is wrong with you autoloading the class, you are also using validate wrong, you should fill out the rules method else it wont trigger the callbacks

Comment: I already put the two methods `failedValidation` and `passedValidation` inside the `AuthRequest` file but error return **Class App\Http\Requests\AuthRequest does not exist**

Comment: Yes as i said something is wrong with how you implemented those methods since it can't load the class probably a syntax error. And i am not certain that this will work if you do not use the rules method to fill your validation

Comment: The way you use the store method() to validate is totally wrong way to use validation in a form request, but it seems like you are not really listening.

Comment: yeah I'm listening Sir, I just created a store method, cause I don't want to create each request file. I want to use one request file for store, update, delete validation. The validation is actually working before, it's just the callback I don't know how to implement.

Comment: but that is not how form request works, the whole point of them is the take the rules and checks them early in the request life cycle. That is not the expected way to use them. Include your whole form request i will look why it wont autoload.

Comment: my point Sir, is it convenient to make each file request for each methods. Like for example `AuthStoreRequest`, `AuthUpdateRequest`, `AuthDestroyRequest`, etc.? I don't think so.

Comment: But the way form request are handling the validation it will automatically resolve the validation. You are not utilizing that build in function. If you think you know what to do go that route, i am not certain that the callbacks will even trigger. I have been working on 4 fairly big scale production systems and never seem your approach. If you do form requests, you put your rules in the rules function.